# Recursive directory with mkdir not working

Tags: php, mkdir, directory, uploading

I am uploading multiple images within a single category and I would like to store each group of images in a unique directory within my 'images/' directory as follows:

'images/unique_category/image1.jpg'

I have the following code but it is not creating a directory. I suspect it has something to do with setting the recursive parameter as 'true' which I believe I have done. Am I using the mkdir function incorrectly?

Thank you!

```
$unique_directory = "../images/".$_POST['item_name'];
if (is_dir($unique_directory)
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  $unique_directory."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . $unique_directory."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
else
  {
  mkdir($unique_directory, 0777, true);
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  $unique_directory."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your PHP error logs?

Comment: For one thing, you have a comma at the end of `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],` which should end with a semi-colon `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];` However it doesn't stop there; that comma could be there for a reason, you're not telling it where to put it. Try replacing it with a semi-colon first.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What you just put there causes an error. His syntax is correct. The first param is the filename and the second is the new destination.

Comment: Yes, I do have errors in the error log:
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PDO_test/php_scripts/upload_form.php on line 41
[05-Jan-2014 21:53:52 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(images/Test/IMG_0003.JPG): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PDO_test/php_scripts/upload_form.php on line 43
[05-Jan-2014 21:53:52 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpBDODjp' to 'images/Test/IMG_0003.JPG' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PDO_test/php_scripts/upload_form.php on

Comment: Yeah my bad. Just noticed it now @Anyone was confused seeing both lines like that, one underneath each other.

Comment: If it's a permission denied error, then you may want to add a `chmod` command before the folder creation method. The created folders may need writing permissions **before** the files are inserted into them.

Comment: What you could aditionally do is check the result of mkdir(), it returns false on failure. Do you have E_WARNING on in your error reporting? "Emits an E_WARNING level error if the relevant permissions prevent creating the directory.", "Emits an E_WARNING level error if the directory already exists."

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have tried to simply add chmod('../images/', 0777) prior to the mkdir() command. This does not seem to work.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of had that feeling. Your syntax seems ok after having a closer look. Can you do a `var_dump();` on all your variables? @user2913891 and see what your HTML source produces after trying to upload, if possible.

Comment: I think I found the problem. A missing `)` in `if (is_dir($unique_directory)` change it to `if (is_dir($unique_directory))` and try it again. @user2913891 I just tested it now and it worked for me.

Comment: Only thing, it didn't put the file in the created folder. I'll see what I can do about that. @user2913891

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me. I am actually using '../' in my code. I tried defining the path directly as well and it did not work. 
I dumped my variables:
[item_name] => Testdir8
            [item_type] => 838
            [item_price] => 83
            [item_description] => test
[unique_directory] => PDO_test/images/Testdir8

Comment: Okay, so, I am using Aptana Studios to do my coding. I just tried to create a directory named "testdir" manually and was then planning on uploading an image to see if the problem was with the if or else statement. It returned an error saying that the directory existed. Turns out it is not displaying new directories in Aptana's file path but is showing them in the actual directory.

Comment: I posted something below for you to try and worked on my (hosted) server. @user2913891

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, give this a try. I tested it on my (hosted) server and it works. Yet, I tested it by placing the files in the root of it, and used `images` instead of `../images` for the `$unique_directory` variable.

I also used the `chmod` command apart from the other function, because the other method did not work.

**N.B.:** If possible, try changing `0777` to `0755`, because using `0777` is not the safest setting.

```
<?php
$filename = $_POST['item_name'];
$unique_directory = "../images";

if (!is_dir($unique_directory . '/' . $filename)){

    mkdir($unique_directory . "/" . $filename);

    chmod("$unique_directory" . "/" .$filename, 0777);
}

if (is_dir($unique_directory))
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $unique_directory . "/" . $filename . "/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);
  echo "1) Stored in: " . $unique_directory . "/" . $filename . "/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
  }

else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $unique_directory . "/" . $filename . "/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);
  echo "2) Stored in: " . $unique_directory . "/" . $filename . "/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
}
?>
```